# What conservation laws would the spontaneous decay of an electron violate?

Tags: photons, electrons, conservation-laws

Why can a moving electron not change into a photon in free space with no third body present? Is there any way to show this through conservation of energy and momentum?

Comment: Conservation of charge?

Comment: ... and conservation of spin and lepton number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, converting an electron to a photon would violate several conservation laws. However I suspect you're interested in seeing how the momentum and energy prohibit the transformation, so let's ignore the other restrictions and just consider this.

We'll keep things simple by treating a non-relativistic particle so the particle momentum is $mv$ and the kinetic energy is $\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2$. The momentum of a photon is $h/\lambda = h\nu/c$, so conservation of momentum gives us:

$$ mv = \frac{h\nu}{c} $$

and the photon frequency is:

$$ \nu = \frac{mvc}{h} \tag{1} $$

Now use energy conservation. Remember that we have to include the rest mass energy of the particle, so we get:

$$ mc^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 = h\nu $$

which gives the frequency:

$$ \nu = \frac{m(c^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}v^2)}{h} \tag{2} $$

Since the photon frequency is the same in both equations (1) and (2) we can equate them to get:

$$ vc = c^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 $$

This rearranges to the quadratic:

$$ v^2 - 2cv +2c^2 = 0 $$

and the solution is:

$$ v = (1 \pm i)c $$

So there is no real velocity at which the transformation could occur.

Answer (score 3):

John Rennie tried to keep things simple in his answer by using a non-relativistic particle. This is one of those cases where a relativistic treatment is simpler. I'll start with the energy-momentum relationship:

$$E^2 = (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2 \tag{1}$$

Equation (1) becomes ${E_e}^2 = (p_ec)^2 + (m_ec^2)^2$ for an electron and $E_p = p_pc$ for a photon, where the subscripts $e$ and $p$ denote the electron and photon. Suppose an electron can be converted into a photon and that both energy and momentum are conserved during the conversion: $E_p = E_e \equiv E$ and $p_p = p_e \equiv p$. (There's no need for the subscripts on energy and momentum if both are conserved quantities.) Equation (1) for the electron becomes

$$E^2 = E^2 + (m_ec^2)^2 \implies m_ec^2 = 0 \tag{2}$$

Equation (2) is false; the electron mass $m_e$ is non-zero. This means that the assumption that an electron can be converted into a photon while conserving both energy and momentum is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I wish now I'd answered this way :-)